# Smart way to overwrite hover and focus styles

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am overwriting the bootstrap pagination so that there is no background/border although to get it to work I fine myself writing a lot of duplicate code

```
.pagination > li > a, 
.pagination > li > a:hover, 
.pagination > li > a:focus, 
.pagination > li > span,
.pagination > li > span:hover,
.pagination > li > span:focus {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: #a8a9ab
}
    .pagination > li > a:hover,
    .pagination > li > a:focus,
    .pagination > li.active > a, 
    .pagination > li.active > a:hover,
    .pagination > li.active > a:focus,
    .pagination > li.active > span,
    .pagination > li.active > span:hover,
    .pagination > li.active > span:focus {
        background: none;
        border: none;
        color: #000
    }
```

I dont want to add `!important` or extra classes into the markup but is there another way I am missing?

This is the best I can do when having to use the !important

```
.pagination > li > a,
.pagination > li > span {
    background: none !important;
    border: none !important;
    color: #a8a9ab !important;
}
    .pagination > li > a:hover,
    .pagination > li > a:focus,
    .pagination > li > span:hover,
    .pagination > li > span:focus,
    .pagination > li.active > a,
    .pagination > li.active > span {
        color: #000 !important;
    }
```

Simple example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FpCEA

Comment: How about changing the "pagination" class to something different and write your own simple css? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT :** I just seen you didn't want any extra class, but I'm afraid you havn't any other way to shorten your CSS without using `!important`. You still can use LESS/SASS instead, which are good alternatives.

---

You can specify your `.pagination` class, adding a new class :

```
<ul class="pagination custom">
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#" >3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then you won't have to use `!important` :

```
.pagination.custom > li > a, 
.pagination.custom > li > span {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: #a8a9ab
}
.pagination.custom > li > a:hover, 
.pagination.custom > li > a:focus, 
.pagination.custom > li > span:hover,
.pagination.custom > li > span:focus,
.pagination.custom > li.active > a,
.pagination.custom > li.active > span {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: #000
}
```

[Codepen fork](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GAatn)